# CXF Web services method with Array Parameter

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I new in web services.I am using apache cxf for my web services.

I have confusion that does cxf web services  support method with "array" parameter.

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think so - judging by chapter 6 of O'Reilly's "Web Services":

http://oreilly.com/catalog/webservess/chapter/ch06.html

Search down the page for "complex type" & you'll see:

```
<complexType name="ArrayOfString">
        <complexContent>
           <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
              <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" 
              wsdl:arrayType="string[]"/>
           </restriction>
        </complexContent>
     </complexType>
```

in a WSDL example.

Hope that's useful to you!